# Drawing a Nyquist diagram animation on python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, controls, nyquist

I am currently trying to create a python code that is supposed to draw an animated nyquist diagram and save it as a gif file.

The problem is, I don't know how to make the *animate* function work. Here is a code I found on the internet that works:

```
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
```

As you may know, *linspace* and *sin* are functions that returns arrays with the sequential values. The *real* and *imag* variables on my code are also arrays with sequential values. *w* variable is an array too, corresponding to the values of *real* and *imag*. I wanted *real* and *imag* to be drawn for every *w* value, thus being the "step" of the animation. What is wrong with my code?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as an
import control

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    G = control.TransferFunction((1),(1,0))
    real, imag, w = control.nyquist(G)
    line.set_data(real, imag)
    return line,**

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have     changed.
anim = an.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=200, blit=True)

#anim.save('GIF.gif', dpi=100, writer='imagemagick')
plt.title('Nyquist Diagram of 1/s')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
plt.xlabel('Real')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are always ploting the current data (real and imag), but according to matplotlib you need to use a list of data which is updated in every iteration.
[Matplotlib - Animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)

In the code below I have created the lists realData and imagData, so in every iteration real and imag are appended to the list and these lists are used as line.set_data arguments.

I have also used the control package just in the begining because it already returns a list containing everything you need to plot.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as an
import control


# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
realData, imagData = [], []
line, = plt.plot([], [], 'rx', animated=True)
G = control.TransferFunction((1),(1,0))
real, imag, w = control.nyquist(G)
print(real)
print(imag)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    realData.append(real[i])
    imagData.append(imag[i])
    line.set_data(realData, imagData)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have     changed.
anim = an.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=range(len(real)), interval=2, blit=True)

#anim.save('GIF.gif', dpi=100, writer='imagemagick')
plt.title('Nyquist Diagram of 1/s')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
plt.xlabel('Real')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. The new code works, but still displays a dashed line on the positive imaginary axis, which I can't figure out how to disable.